# Django-cms Edit model placeholder before model is added

Tags: django, django-cms

Is there a good way to implement editing of a PlaceholderField before the model is added to an app?

I have an app with an apphook, and at present one has to create the model in the admin interface, save it (causing it to appear on the website), and then add the CMS content to the already-visible rendering of the model. Clearly this isn't very good.

Ideally I would like to be able to create the Placeholder content 'inline' along with the rest of the model.

What would be the best way to go about this? Is there an existing method, or do I hack the admin interface and the model's save method using the CMS API?

Thanks

Comment: The simplest way I work around this is to add an `is_published` BooleanField to the model, and only display instances that are published. For my use cases, this gives the author as much time as they want to add/arrange/tweak content in a Placeholder before the instance is publicly visible.

Comment: @Brandon Thanks. How do you stop them publishing the wrong article after filling in the content? (Or complaining about having to find the model on the CMS in order to finish editing it...)

Comment: I've been walking them through how to "Save and Continue" to keep working on the same model. Otherwise I have to trust that they know which instance they want to publish.

Comment: You can add the field `is_published` in `list_display` and `list_filter` in order to easily distinguish published from non published articles.